# VB.NET: Anonymous function to new thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have this code:

```
Public Sub Submit(
    ByVal reasonId As Integer, 
    ByVal email As String, 
    ByVal message As String
)
    '[Argument validation code here]
    EmailController.sendMail(reasonId, email, message)
End Sub
```

I want to spin this off in a new thread so `Submit()` returns right after creating and start the thread.

In C#, I could do something like this:

```
new Thread(() => {
        EmailController.sendMail(reasonId, email, message)
}).Start();
```

How do I do this in VB.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new Thread(Sub() EmailController.sendMail(reasonId, email, message)).Start()
```