# Create a new thread in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am trying to create a new thread using an anonymous function but I keep getting errors. Here is my code:

```
New Thread(Function() 
    'Do something here
End Function).Start
```

Here are the errors I get:

New:

> Syntax Error

End Function:

> 'End Function' must be preceded by a matching 'Function'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET: Anonymous function to new thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837396/vb-net-anonymous-function-to-new-thread)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There's two ways to do this;

1. With the `AddressOf` operator to an existing method

   ```
   Sub MyBackgroundThread()
     Console.WriteLine("Hullo")
   End Sub
   ```

   And then create and start the thread with;

   ```
   Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf MyBackgroundThread)
   thread.Start()
   ```
2. Or as a lambda function.

   ```
   Dim thread as New Thread(
     Sub() 
       Console.WriteLine("Hullo")
     End Sub
   )
   thread.Start()
   ```

Comment: tanks buddy this helped

Comment: it doesn't work I get this error... System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'MapRangeBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

I still want it to work in the background,  i.e. lazy load.

Answer (score 5):

It is called a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) in VB.  The syntax is all wrong, you need to actually declare a variable of type Thread to use the New operator.  And the lambda you create must be a valid substitute for the argument you pass to the Thread class constructor.  None of which take a delegate that return a value so you must use Sub, not Function.  A random example:

```
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim t As New Thread(Sub()
                                Console.WriteLine("hello thread")
                            End Sub)
        t.Start()
        t.Join()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that multiline lambdas only work in VS2010.

Comment: Not a Windows Phone problem, VS2010 required.

Comment: Nitpicking time: a lambda expression is just an alternative syntax to write an anonymous function. Telling a lambda expression isn't an anonymous function is like telling a square isn't a rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

What is called has to be a functinon not a sub.

Single line(has to return value):

```
Dim worker As New Thread(New ThreadStart(Function() 42))
```

Multiline:

```
Dim worker As New Thread(New ThreadStart(Function()
                                                     ' Do something here
                                                 End Function))
```

Source: [Threading, Closures, and Lambda Expressions in VB.Net](http://mlindegarde.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/threading-closures-and-lambda-expressions-in-vb-net/)