# Do something in the Background without freezing the Program

Tags: vb.net

In my program, I have a timer which checks to make sure you are connected to the internet and to check if you're connected to a VPN. the Code is rather simple

```
 Public Function IsInternetConnected() As Boolean
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping("google.com", 2000) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
Public Function IsVPNConnected() As Boolean
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping("10.0.2.29", 2000) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

The problem is that every time it checks the program will hang for a few seconds and will not let you do anything else. Is there a way I can have it check constantly without freezing the application?

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If IsVPNConnected() = True Then
        BtnVPN.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        BtnVPN.Text = "Connected"
    Else
        BtnVPN.BackColor = Color.Red
        BtnVPN.Text = "Disconnected"
    End If

    If IsInternetConnected() = True Then
        BtnInternet.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        BtnInternet.Text = "Connected"
    Else
        BtnInternet.BackColor = Color.Red
        BtnInternet.Text = "Disconnected"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the timer a windows forms timer?  Show the code for the timer.

Comment: Might be a job for backgroundorker or threads depending on what you are going with it.

Comment: I added the code for the timer

Comment: Timer that starts a backgroundworker (and pauses the timer), when backgrounder worker finishes it changes the button properties (and continues the timer). You can look into that.

Comment: where are you calling this function from?

Comment: You need to call the function asyncronously. make a new thread if the function itself doesn't come with an asyncronous version.

Comment: [Ping.SendAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendasync) (event-driven) or [Ping.SendPingAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync) (awaitable Task). Suspend the Timer until the async Ping returns. Note that Ping may not work as intended - unless *manually* routed - in some networks (badly configured, as most *User* computers/small networks are).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i use a BackgroundWorker with a timer tick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811048/how-can-i-use-a-backgroundworker-with-a-timer-tick)

Comment: This was last asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134507/verify-internet-connection-in-vb-net and it was closed as a duplicate at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your functions to be in a backgroundworker and then call the background worker instead of the functions directly when you want the functionality of your current function.  This will prevent your application from freezing while the functions are running.

It would go something like this:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    SyncLock internetconnected
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping("google.com", 2000) Then
            internetconnected = True
        Else
            internetconnected = False
        End If
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Then you call the background worker when you want it to do something like this:

```
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
```

Comment: you should add a lock to the variable. and make sure you don't run the worker more than once at the same time. also why do you put True and False in quotes?

Comment: I just wrote it quickly.  You are right, it should not have quotes.

Answer (score 1):

A ping can take a long time to execute. Perhaps try using: `System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.com")` instead.

Regardless, as others have stated, you need to run your check code in a new thread. See the answer here: [Create a new thread in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182563/create-a-new-thread-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

I'd **get rid of the Timer** and use a task instead.  Here I have started the task in the Shown event.

```
Private tmrTask As task
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    tmrTask = Task.Run(Sub()
                           Do
                               Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                  If IsVPNConnected() Then
                                                      BtnVPN.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                                                      BtnVPN.Text = "Connected"
                                                  Else
                                                      BtnVPN.BackColor = Color.Red
                                                      BtnVPN.Text = "Disconnected"
                                                  End If

                                                  If IsInternetConnected() Then
                                                      BtnInternet.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                                                      BtnInternet.Text = "Connected"
                                                  Else
                                                      BtnInternet.BackColor = Color.Red
                                                      BtnInternet.Text = "Disconnected"
                                                  End If
                                              End Sub)
                               '<<< adjust sleep
                               Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) '<<< this would be the same as interval from timer
                           Loop
                       End Sub)
End Sub
```